# Cant get the value from Drop down list

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json, spring-boot

im populating datas from json to dropdown list.

```
$(function() {     
            $('#productList').append($('<option/>').attr("value", key).text(data[key].productName));
            
    })
```

here data is the json object. when i execute this the value is multiplying whenever i close and open the dropdown list.
to prevent this i did

```
$('#productList').empty();
```

but the problem now is when i select an option and close the dropdown it resets .
so how do i select an option and get its value without repeating the options.
thanks in advance

my html code is

```
<label>Select The Product:</label><select id="productList">
</select>
```

Comment: Don't keep re-adding them?

Answer (score 1):

```js
let data = [{
    "name": "product 1",
    "price": "100"
  },
  {
    "name": "product 2",
    "price": "200"
  },
  {
    "name": "product 3",
    "price": "500"
  }
];

$(function() {    
  $.each(data, function (key, value) {
    $('#product')
    .append($('<option/>')
    .attr("value", key)
    .text(data[key].name));
    
  })        
            
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="product" name="product">
</select>
```

Comment: Please always consider leaving a comment explaining why your solution will solve the OP's problems.

Answer (score 0):

**Try using for loop:**

[Read More about for loop](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
        var data = [
    {
        productName: "Product 1",
        value: "000"
    },
    {
        productName: "Product 2",
        value: "001"
    },
    {
        productName: "Product 3",
        value: "002"
    },
    {
        productName: "Product 4",
        value: "004"
    },
    {
        productName: "Product 5",
        value: "005"
    },
    {
        productName: "Product 6",
        value: "006"
    },
    {
        productName: "Product 7",
        value: "007"
    }
];

var count = data.length;
for(var i = 0; i< count; i++){
    $('#productList').append('<option>'+data[i]['productName']+'</option')
}

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>Select The Product:</label>
<select id="productList">

</select>
```